# Fixed stuck while I use for loop to restore many SQL Server databases

Tags: c#, database-restore

I need to loop through all my databases in a TreeView, then choose TreeNode for the database name to restore. My code works fine if I choose only 1, 2 or 3 databases to restore. But if I choose many databases it will get hung.

Please check my code and help me..

```
            foreach (TreeNode tn in trvList.Nodes)
            {
                if (tn.Checked == true)
                { 
                        strFileName = GetFileTorestor(strRealdb);//Check File Directory to restore example : C:data\tn.text.
                        if (strFileName != "")
                        {
                            RestoreDatabase(res, tn);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strErorLog += "\r\n -" + tn.Text;
                            blIsEror = true;
                            MessageBox.Show("Database " + tn.Text + " has not found!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        }                                 
                }
            }       


    /// <summary>
    /// Restore database according to treenode selected.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="res"></param>
    /// <param name="tn"></param>
    private void RestoreDatabase(Restore res,TreeNode tn)
    {
        res.Database = tn.Text;
        res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        res.Devices.AddDevice(strFileName, DeviceType.File);
        res.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        this.pgrRestore.Value = 0;
        this.pgrRestore.Maximum = 100;
        //res.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
        res.PercentCompleteNotification = 5;
        res.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(sqlRestore_PercentComplete);
        res.SqlRestore(DBHelper.Server);
        stLog += "\r\n " + tn.Text + " from file " + strFileName;//Record database name already restore to log text
        txtLog.Text = stLog;
        txtLog.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: (Note: StackOverflow is not code review site...) It is unclear what do you mean "stuck". Does it mean if you select 4 databases it simply do nothing? There is nothing in code that you've posted that make destinction between 3 and 4... you may have some other code that make 4+ special...

Comment: P.S. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ *is* a code review site.

Comment: Dear Alexei, it means that if i choose many database then it will loop all databases to restore without waiting the previous task to be completed. that why my code stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean by stuck that the UI freezes for a while then that is because you are excuting your work on the main thread which is the UI thread. No UI interaction is possible as the thread is busy doing your work. You should have a look at [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to perform your work in the background and report progress to the UI.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea, i'll check out for BackgroundWorker to solve my problem..